# W3C Compliant WYSIWYG?

Tags: wysiwyg, w3c

Could someone recommend me a WYSIWYG editor that is W3C compliant and has decent functionality?

Comment: I managed to stumble across this one: http://cutesoft.net/example/xmloutput.aspx

Seems compliant and functional, any one had experience using it?

Answer (score 3):

The whole concept of WYSIWYG goes against the spirit of the HTML specs.

I'm not sure if there are any good WYSIWYM editors meant for the web. Lyx is great for documents, but not websites.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Amaya, which is [W3C's Editor/Browser](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/).